# pycurl READFUNCTION with a bytestream

Tags: python, pycurl

Is there a way to write a callback function for pycurl's READFUNCTION that does not return a string? I am planning on sending blocks of binary data via pycurl. i tried writing a callback function that does this:

```
def read_callback(self, size):
  for block in data:
    yield block
```

but pycurl exits with an error that says the return type must be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "read function" must return a string of bytes -- remember, libcurl is a wrapper on an underlying C library, so of course it's type-picky!-).  However, it can perfectly be a binary string of bytes (in Python `2.*` at least -- I don't think pycurl works with Python 3 anyway), so of course it can return "blocks of binary data" -- as long as they're encoded into strings of bytes and respect the `size` constraint.

What you just encoded, when called, returns a "generator function" -- obviously no good.  Assuming `data` is a list of non-empty byte strings, you need to dice and slice it appropriately, returning each time a string of bytes, with `return`, definitely **not** `yield` (!).

Not sure where that mysterious `data` of yours comes from -- let's assume you mean `self.data` instead.  Then you need to keep track, in other instance variables, of the current index into `self.data` and possibly -- if the items are longer than `size` -- of the "yet unsent part" of the current piece, too.

E.g., it could be:

```
class MySender(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.i = 0
    self.rest = 0
  def readfunction(self, size):
    if self.i >= len(self.data):
      return ''
    result = self.data[self.i][self.rest:self.rest+size]
    self.rest += size
    if self.rest >= len(self.data[self.i]):
      self.i += 1
      self.rest = 0
```

If self.data's items are other kinds of binary data (not already encoded as byte strings), you can turn them into byte strings e.g. with help from Python library modules such as `struct` and `array`.

Comment: I see. Instead of writing a callback function, I used cStringIO. I just wrote the blocks of data to the cStringIO instance and passed the read function of the cStringIO instance to the pycurl instance.

I just thought I would try writing the read callback so I can implement "chunked" transfers, but figured pycurl is better off handing that himself.

Comment: @maranas, sure, cStringIO is simpler if you can afford to copy the data there, my code applies only when you can't afford that;-).